# How to Call a Variable from another Function within the same Object?

Tags: javascript

I just wish to know if there is a simple way to call a variable from another function within the same Object?

```
var comedy = {
schadenfreude: function() {
    var number = prompt("Provide me a number.");
},
irony: function() {
    this.schadenfreude();
    for(i = 0; i < this.schadenfreude.number(); i++){
        return i;
    }
}
};
console.log(comedy.irony());
```

In this example I wish to grab the `var number` from the `schadenfreude function` and use that prompted number in my for loop with the `irony function`.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Make that `schadenfreude` function return `number` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "number" variable in your "schadenfreude" function is local to that function. Even if you could get to it (you can't), it would do you no good.

What you (probably) want is:

```
var comedy = {
    number: 0,
    schadenfreude: function() {
        this.number = prompt("Provide me a number.");
    },
    irony: function() {
        this.schadenfreude();
        for(i = 0; i < this.number; i++){
            alert(i);
        };
    }
};
console.log(comedy.irony());
```

Alternatively, you could have "schadenfreude" assign the value to a "number" property on the object, so that you'd refer to `this.number` in the "irony" function. In either case, as I noted in the comment in the code, the fact that your `for` loop has that `return` statement means that the "irony" function will always return zero if the user gives you any non-negative number, and `undefined` otherwise.

Comment: Thank you.  That's what I needed to know.  I knew the var was local to the function but I wasn't sure if the rules changed since it was all housed within the object.  I guess the var would have to be defined within the object level to be used by all the functions within the object.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I plan too when Stack Overflow allows me in 7 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to grab a local variable from another member defined on the same object.  That's not directly possible.  Local variables are scoped to the defining function / member and there isn't a way to access them directly.  The function must explicitly return them to the caller in some manner for them to be accessed